# Invoke Kernel Failure through Java

Tags: java, kernel

Is it possible to purposely invoke a kernel panic through java?

Possibly by writing malformed addresses to memory through the Unsafe method library, I know I could use runtime to execute terminal commands, but I'm looking to accomplish this in a more java oriented way.

Comment: Why would you want to cause a kernel panic?

Comment: How would you invoke kernel panic from terminal?

Answer (score 0):

No unless you count security holes because invoking kernel panic from a user program **is** a security hole. Using invalid memory would only terminate your program.